# How to convert a shapefile in map projection coordinates to geographic coordinates?

Tags: shapefile, matplotlib-basemap, r-maptools

I am trying to use basemap to plot NYC with a shapefile. However, the shapefiles provided by NYC (https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/districts-download-metadata.page) are don't use the proper coordinates to be read by the shapefile.

My IDE gives me this message:ValueError: shapefile must have lat/lon vertices  - it looks like this one has vertices
in map projection coordinates. You can convert the shapefile to geographic
coordinates using the shpproj utility from the shapelib tools
(http://shapelib.maptools.org/shapelib-tools.html)

I looked it up but have no idea how to use it. Could someone help explain how to use that utility or have an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [I would highly suggest using a tool like QGIS and transforming the shapefile to another coordinate system like WGS84 before using it. I'm not sure, but I bet the one you have is using state plane.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs)

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you